# What is the cellular automaton shown as loading screen on Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: language-agnostic, cellular-automata

When entering a query in Wolfram Alpha you usually see an animation shown for a couple of seconds before the result is displayed. It seems to be a cellular automaton with 3 distinctive states.

I would like to know what this particular automaton is called, and where I can find informations about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a cellular automaton with 5 states. The rule is `3457/357/5` using [Golly's](http://golly.sourceforge.net/) notation.

It has 5 states: `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`. In each step, cells behave as follows:

- `0` -> `1` if 3, 5 or 7 of its eight neighbors are `1`, or `0` otherwise
- `1` -> `1` if 3, 4, 5 or 7 of its eight neighbors are `1`, or `2` otherwise
- `2` -> `3`
- `3` -> `4`
- `4` -> `0`

Here is an oscillator with period 15:

[image]

Here is a puffer with period 24:

[image]

Comment: That's it! The link to golly is extremely helpful. Never heard of it before!

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle of my JavaScript implementation of Wolfram's specific animation. Had to grab a screenshot of one of the frames to initialize it lol. The one I grabbed was pretty simple, but I'd love to know the absolute starting point they use. https://jsfiddle.net/iAmMortos/espncctd/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very fast matlab implementation of Wolfram Alpha's cellular automation:

```
rng(38); % 31 lasts a while / 38 has two oscillators / 39 lasts longer /42 lasts muuuuch longer
X = randi([0 4],30,40);

[a,b] = size(X);

initialFig = figure('toolbar','none','menubar','none');
[x,y]      = meshgrid(1:b,1:a);
scathandle = scatter(x(:),y(:),20*X(:)+1,X(:)+1,'filled');
colormp    = linspace(1,0.4,5)'*[1 1 1]; colormap(colormp);
axis([0 b+1 0 a+1]); axis off; set(gca,'position',[0 0 1 1]); set(gcf,'toolbar','none','menubar','none','color','w','numbertitle','off','name',''); axis equal;

n = [a 1:a-1]; % The previous row
s = [2:a 1];   % The next row
e = [2:b 1];   % The next column
w = [b 1:b-1]; % The previous column

[A,B,C] = meshgrid(1:a,1:b,[0 1]);

Xnew = X;
while 1
    N = (X(n,:)==1) + (X(s,:)==1) + (X(:,e)==1) + (X(:,w)==1) + (X(n,e)==1) + (X(n,w)==1) + (X(s,e)==1) + (X(s,w)==1); % Look for the total number of nieghbours == 1

    Xnew(X>=2) = mod(X(X>=2)+1,5); % if state is greater or equal to 2, increment 1 modulo 5
    Xnew(X==0) = (N(X==0)==3 | N(X==0)==5 | N(X==0)==7); % if state is 0, turn to 1 when neighbours equal 3,5 or 7. Leave 0 otherwise.
    Xnew(X==1) = 2 - (N(X==1)==3 | N(X==1)==4 | N(X==1)==5 | N(X==1)==7); % if state is 1, turn to 2 unless neighbours equal 3, 4 or 5. In the latter case, leave 1.
    X = Xnew;
    set(scathandle,'cdata',X(:)+1,'sizedata',20*X(:)+1);
    drawnow;

    if ~ishandle(initialFig)
        return
    end
end
```

I guess that, at any moment, someone will find this useful (somehow).

Answer (score -2):

It's **Conway's Game of Life**.  There's a very good wikipedia article on it, I suggest you go take a look there.

Comment: This can't be true, since Convay's Game of Life has only 2 possible states: dead and alive. The automaton shown on WA's loading page however has 3 states: empty, small circle and big circle. Maybe it is some variation of Game of Life? If so can you point me to a description/particular implementation of it?